# Laravel 10 404 error trying to download existing files on Windows 10/IIS

Tags: file, download, windows-10, http-status-code-404, laravel-10

I'm getting 404 errors trying to download existing files in Laravel 10 using IIS on Windows 10/SQL Server.

Files are stored in the files table with a UUID and folder_id. Paths to folders are stored in the folders table.

[image: Files table]

[image: Folders table]

Download links on the page go to the show function in the FileController with the UUID as a parameter. The FileController uses a trait to get the storage path to the folder and append the filename, then should download the file.

FileController:

```
    public function show(File $file): StreamedResponse
    {
        return $this->download($file);
    }
```

FileTrait:

```
    public function download(File $file): StreamedResponse
    {
        $folder = $file->folder()->first();

        $folderPath = $this->getFolderPath($folder); // [in FolderTrait]

        \Log::debug('download folderPath: ' . $folderPath);

        $storagePath = $this->getStoragePath($folderPath);

        \Log::debug('download storagePath: ' . $storagePath);

        $path = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [$storagePath, $file->filename]);

        \Log::debug('download path: ' . $path);

        if (file_exists($path) === false) {
            $this->logInfo("File $file->filename not found at $path");

            abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return Storage::disk('local')->download($path, $file->filename, [
            'Content-Type' => $file->mime_type
        ]);
    }
```

FolderTrait:

```
    public function getFolderPath(Model $folder): string
    {
        return $folder->path;
    }

    public function getStoragePath(string $path): string
    {
        $storagePath = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path);

        return str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $storagePath);
    }
```

When I click on the download links I get a 404 error. I expect the file to download since the generated path is correct, the file exists on the server, and the web users have permissions to read the file.

Log:
`download path: C:\inetpub\the-anchor-bridge\storage\app\knowledge-base\policies\human-resources-policies\employee-policy-book.pdf`

`File employee-policy-book.pdf not found at C:\inetpub\the-anchor-bridge\storage\app\knowledge-base\policies\human-resources-policies\employee-policy-book.pdf`

The file exists on the server at that path:
[image: File in directory]

IUSR and IIS_USRS have read permissions:

[image]
[image]